# How do i check for multiple terms in message.content.lower

Tags: discord.py

I'm programming a bot to stop my friends from playing league, but  I can't figure out a way to check that multiple words are in the message.

```
if 'league' in message.content.lower():
    response = random.choice(Response)
    await message.channel.send(response)
```

What I'm doing here, is copying pasting this and changing the `league` word to another term. How do I make it just one line of code instead of a whole 100 lines?

Answer (score 0):

if you mean multiple seperate words you could use the built-in any() function. You could also use the "or" keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You can take use of the [`any()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/any) function:

```py
some_words = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']

if any(word in message.content.lower() for word in some_words):
    ...
```